# AngularJS uibModal reusable function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I couldn't come up with normal title. Sorry for that. 
So the problem is that in a big project, with big business logic there are a lot of modals. And every new modal is the same code with little changes, like templateUrl, controller and such things. This is how pop up is getting called now:

```
return uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: current.path + 'url.html',
                    controller: 'AppController',
                    windowClass: 'PopUp',
                    size: 'md',
                    resolve: {
                        disabled: [function () {
                            return scope.disabled;
                        }]
                    }
                }).result.then(function( comment ){
                    record.comment = comment;
                })
```

And this routine never ends. So what I'm interested in is - what is the best practice to reduce the same code(same to this situation) in your project? Should you use service? Or just create global function?

Comment: how about just wrapping this code inside a function and providing the right controller and template as arguments on each call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AngularJS you should always avoid global functions. Services were created for this purpose. I also use `$uibModal` and was tired of writing the same thing over and over again.

I made a `ModalService` which allowed me to abstract away a lot of the repetitive code:

```
function ModalService() {
  var ModalService = this;

  ModalService.basicModal = function(options) {
                var _options = options || {};
                return $uibModal.open({
                    animation: angular.isDefined(_options.animation) ? _options.animation : true,
                    keyboard: angular.isDefined(_options.keyboard) ? _options.keyboard :  true,
                    backdrop: _options.backdrop || 'static',
                    size: _options.size || 'sm',
                    templateUrl: _options.templateUrl || 'templates/modal-message.html',  //default template in case user does not provide one
                    controller: _options.controller || ModalMessageCtrl, // a default controller in case user does not provide one
                    controllerAs: _options.controllerAs || 'vm',
                    resolve: options.resolve || {}
                });

  };

  ModalService.simpleModal = function(options) {
  ...
  };
}
```

You can define many varieties of modals that can be invoked easily from the controller:

```
ModalService.basicModal();
ModalService.simpleModal();
// etc...
```

And all of these can accept optional parameters to customize the modal:

```
ModalService.basicModal({
  size: 'lg'
});
ModalService.simpleModal({
  templateUrl: "my-custom-template.html",
  controller: function($scope) {
    //some custom inline controller
  }
}).result.then(function() { //do something });
// etc...
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer I was looking for. By the way, now all modal templates are in the same directory, where the page is. Is this right way? Than I have to pass full path as parameter to service

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$uibModalProvider.options`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) to set the default options during the configuration phase of the application.

```
app.config(function($uibModalProvider) {
    $uibModalProvider.options = {
        windowClass: 'PopUp',
        size: 'md'
    };
});
```

If you're using UI Bootstrap 2.1.0 or greater you can also leverage angular's component based architecture to remove some of the extra cruft when opening a modal.

Given a component defined as follows:

```
app.component('myModal', {
    bindings: {close: '&', dismiss: '&', resolve: '<'},
    controller: MyModalController,
    templateUrl: 'myModal.html'
});
```

You can leverage the component in a modal as follows:

```
$uibModal.open({
    component: 'myModal',
    resolve: {
        // pass data to component
    }
}).result.then(function() {
    // Modal closed
}).catch(function() {
    // Modal dismissed
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really useful information and I will use it for sure